# Appium server is not getting connect with the emulator

Tags: appium

I have recently started working with appium. I successfully invoked a dummy application using appium in android emulator.

But, when I tried our actual app, a pop-up is thrown saying:

> Application Error The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (File:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Upon accept the application is closed.

I am able to access the same app manually in emulator and no pop-up is thrown. I have attached the screen shots of the issue and the appium setup. please kindly help if any one of u have faced similar issue.

Error message in eclipse is as follows, also attached the appium log file. plz help

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
>   System info: host: 'CESCHNDES-0007', ip: '192.168.28.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
>   Session ID: f7ec8638-d504-45dd-92dc-18be645af04d
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, app=D:\Testing\Kinnser\Kinnserbuild\Kinnser5.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=Android, appActivity=com.kinnser.mobile.KinnserMobile, desired={platform=WINDOWS, app=D:\Testing\Kinnser\Kinnserbuild\Kinnser5.apk, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=Android, appActivity=com.kinnser.mobile.KinnserMobile, device=Android Emulator, appPackage=com.kinnser.mobile, version=4.4.2}, appPackage=com.kinnser.mobile, version=4.4.2, platformVersion=4.1, databaseEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, device=Android Emulator, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:610)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getTitle(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
>   at test.FirstSample.main(FirstSample.java:41)

Comment: could you share the piece of code for your desired capabilities getting set for Appium?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.1");
     cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Please suggest ASAP.

Comment: cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.Honkampkrueger.hk");
    
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".MainActivity");
    
    AndroidDriver and = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    
     and.startActivity("appPackage","com.example.android.apis", null, null);

Comment: And the file path is :


File appDir = new File("Src");
    
    File app = new File(appDir, "honkamp.apk");

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is could possibly be your set desired capabilities as I could infer from the logs if. [Server capabilities](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?java#appium-server-capabilities)  suggests that :

```
platform=WINDOWS //incorrect assignment
app=D:\Testing\Kinnser\Kinnserbuild\Kinnser5.apk
javascriptEnabled=true
acceptSslCerts=true 
browserName=Android //incorrect assignment
appActivity=com.kinnser.mobile.KinnserMobile
device=Android Emulator
appPackage=com.kinnser.mobile 
version=4.4.2 //preferred platformVersion
platformVersion=4.1
databaseEnabled=false 
webStorageEnabled=false 
warnings={}
takesScreenshot=true
```

You could change the following :

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID)‌​; 
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.1");
```

to

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID)‌​; 
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
//platform already specified
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.1"); //platform version of android
```

Comment: Thanks ..But i have a major issue that My emulator is taking too much time to get launched completely and when i am trying to run my app through appium server.                                                                           It is giving error :  The emulator takes a lot of time to load completely and due to this when i am trying to invoke an android app through appium server is generating the error : 
A new session could not be created. (Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched).

Comment: And often the android is getting stuck on the Android screen and not getting launched further. so till I launched emulator completely , I cant do nothing to invoke apps. please help.

Comment: I am expecting you might be using AVD. No advertising though but I personally use Genymotion to create Emulators which is much faster.

Comment: Yes I am using AVD.. So how can i get rid off this issue please suggest.

Comment: sorry, don't have much idea about the performance improvement of the AVD